# Watch application screen size changes in Capacitor/Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, capacitor

The real-world use case is to detect split screen and tablet fold when Capacitor application runs. It looks like Android handles this with "configuration changes", while there seems to be no explicit mention of it in Capacitor APIs.

How can the changes in application screen size be watched?

Can this reliably be done with WebView window `resize` event?

Comment: you can always detect window resize with window.resize event. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Answer (score 1):

```js
const webView = document.getElementById('your-id'); 
const initialWidth = webView.clientWidth;
const initialHeight = webView.clientHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const newWidth = webView.clientWidth;
  const newHeight = webView.clientHeight;

  if (newWidth !== initialWidth || newHeight !== initialHeight) {

    initialWidth = newWidth;
    initialHeight = newHeight;
  }
});
```

Please note that this method relies on the WebView's resize event, which may not be triggered explicitly in response to Android's configuration changes. WebView may resize for various reasons, such as orientation changes or content layout changes, so you'll need to filter out false positives.

To make this more reliable, you might consider using native Android events to detect screen configuration changes. Capacitor allows you to create custom plugins that can interface with native code. You could create a custom Capacitor plugin for Android that listens to Android's configuration change events and sends the information to your web app.